# I can not get data from setResult Method while debug shows it has extras ..?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want that from second activity that is `ShowActivity` when I press back it returns the `ArrayList` but I cannot get it. In debug `setResult()` method shows the array but in next point on `activityResult` data is null why?
 In first activity , `onActivityResult` data is null.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent show=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowActivity.class);
                // Create a Bundle and Put Bundle in to it
                Bundle bundleObject = new Bundle();
                bundleObject.putSerializable("key", showImagelist);
                show.putExtras(bundleObject);
                //startActivity(show);
                startActivityForResult(show,COUNTER_ARRAY_LIST);
        }
    });

   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==SELECT_IMAGE){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && null!=data){
          for (int i=0,c=0,r=0;i<count;i++,c++){
              if(c==coloumn){
                    c=0;
                    r++;
               }

          }

            ImageUri=data.getData();
            imageItemBin=new ImageItemBin();
            imageItemBin.setImage(ImageUri.toString());
            publicSelectedImage.add(imageItemBin);

            gridAdaptor=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,publicSelectedImage,this);
            gridview.setAdapter(gridAdaptor);

        }
    }
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CAMERA)
    {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){
            Bitmap mphoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            String stringImage=BitMapToString(mphoto);

            imageItemBin=new ImageItemBin();
            imageItemBin.setImage(stringImage);
            //imageItemBin.setImage(picturePth.toString());
            publicSelectedImage.add(imageItemBin);
            gridAdaptor=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,publicSelectedImage,this);
            gridview.setAdapter(gridAdaptor);
            //gridAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

           // tvcounter.setText(counter);
            //publicSelectedImage=selectedImage;
        }
    }
    if(requestCode==COUNTER_ARRAY_LIST){
        //if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){
            Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
            showImagelist=(ArrayList<ImageItemBin>)bundle.getSerializable("BackArrayList");
            int sizeOfArrry=showImagelist.size();
            btnShow.setText("Show ( " + Integer.toString(sizeOfArrry) + " ) ");
            showImagelist.notifyAll();
        //}
    }


}
```

**ShowActivity.java:**

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent back=new Intent();
    Bundle b=new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("BackArrayList",showlist1);
    back.putExtras(b);
    //startActivity(back,b);
    setResult(2,back);
    finish();
    //startActivityForResult(back,MainActivity.COUNTER_ARRAY_LIST,b);
}
```

Comment: and i declare it also as follows                                                                                                                     public static int COUNTER_ARRAY_LIST=2;

Comment: What type of data are you trying to send as result?

Comment: Arraylist of type Modelclass

Comment: Method `setResult(2,back);` should be `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, back);` You also should try executing your code before the call to `super.onBackPressed()`

Comment: ArrayList<ImageItemBin> showlist1=new ArrayList<ImageItemBin>();

Comment: I suppose ImageItemBin implements Serializable interface, doesn't it?

Comment: yes it impliments

Comment: thanks a lot @aschattney . it works perfect. i have comment the super.onBackPressed() . it get data. but why super should not used before code?

Comment: and answer in answer box so it can be usefull to any one.@aschattney

Comment: @Dharmishtha ok i'll write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the result has to be set before the method `super.onBackPressed()` gets executed:

Look at the code for the `onBackPressed()` at [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onBackPressed%28%29)

This method would call the method `finishAfterTransition()`, if no fragments are available on the backstack. In the method `finishAfterTransition()` you see a call to `finish()`. So before you set the result in your code, the system moves the activity to state "finished" and setting the result afterwards is ignored.
So you have to ensure that you set the result before the call to `super.onBackPressed()` in order to be sure that your result gets set before the activity gets finished.